# How May I Tell Who Keeps Deleting Legitimate Comments In Order To Take Action?

Tags: feature-request, moderators, comments

I have a comment to a question that I need clarified before attempting to answer a question.  The question has had many off-topic comments which were either deleted or moved to chat.  My comment is on-target and is something that requires clarification from the OP before I can answer and is therefore a legitimate comment.  Someone(s) keeps deleting the comment.

I'd like to find out who it is in order to inquire why they are deleting a valid comment.  As it is right now, there's no way to find out whom it is, and there's no recourse that I'm aware of for someone maliciously deleting valid comments.

Question:
[My girlfriend has mentioned disowning her 14 y/o transgender daughter](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/my-girlfriend-has-mentioned-disowning-her-14-y-o-transgender-daughter)

Comment: The recourse for "maliciously deleting valid comments" would be to contact the CMs. I'm not suggesting that is appropriate in this situation, simply stating that it would be the recourse if that was happening.

Comment: As Goethe stated, "...misunderstandings and neglect create more confusion in this world than trickery and malice. At any rate, the last two are certainly much less frequent." This is based on a misunderstanding of the purpose of comments and the roles mods *are assigned* by SO.

Comment: @anongoodnurse How is a comment intended to elicit clarification not a correct - in fact the most correct - use of comments on questions, and a way to reduce misunderstandings and neglect?

Comment: @Warren Drew - Can you please link to anything where I say that a comment for clarification is wrong? Otherwise I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @anongoodnurse When you say the question, which talks about a comment for clarification, "is based on a misunderstanding of the purpose of comments".  Note that there is no way for the reader to see whether the comment actually asked for clarification, so we're supposed to take the question in good faith.  If we saw the deleted comment and felt it didn't actually ask for clarification, it would be better to say so, rather than to impugn the question, which might equally apply to a comment that validly asked for clarification.

Comment: @Warren Dew - You quite misunderstood my comment, and ironically may have been the exception to the "rule" I quoted.

Answer (score 5):

Those comments are not being maliciously deleted - the moderator team has been removing them as they count as noise.

This question has received a really high number of comments - and in order to limit this we have been deleting as many as possible (76 so far) and recommending that people use the chatroom which has been setup specifically for this post.

Your comment is not valid as per those guidelines listed. Remember, comments are supposed to be temporary, for clarification etc. Yours is trying to put a viewpoint across, and is an answer, not a comment. You think it is on-target, but this is just not correct.

And it will keep being removed.

Why not try posting an answer?

And in answer to your Question title - you won't get to know who deletes them unless the person deleting decides to tell you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51772/discussion-on-answer-by-rory-alsop-how-may-i-tell-who-keeps-deleting-legitimate).